# How to debug asp.net website code hosted on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, visual-studio-debugging

I am getting some issues/bugs in my code. I need to debug the code from my visual studio, but code is deployed on IIS.

Can you please provide some solution so that I can debug the code and find the error

I am using Windows XP.

Comment: If your XP installation supports IIS, I would install that locally, so that your development environment matches your production environment as closely as possible. Then you can debug by attaching to your local IIS.

Comment: Are the IIS server and Visual Studio on the same machine?

Comment: There are both two scenarios:
1. IIS and Visual Studio on the same system (My Machine)
2. IIS on other system (QC system) and Visual Studio on my system

Answer (score 2):

If you need to debug a remote server, then you should refer to the following link:

[Remote IIS Debugging : Debug your ASP.NET Application which is hosted on "Remote IIS Server"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio)

(interestingly enough, by the same author as the link provided by @Gaurav123)

**EDIT:**
This is a rather complicated process, that is why people are posting links rather than giving you a full answer.